# Make div fill height while respecting toolbar height

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am making a simple layout, with a toolbar, a sidenav, and a div for content:

[Here is a stackblitz of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-qerk2d)

> sidebar.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="full-layout-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav-container" mode="side" opened="true">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded">
          <mat-icon *ngIf="!isExpanded">chevron_right</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="isExpanded">chevron_left</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
        <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">Home</p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z4 no-margin" color="primary"></mat-toolbar>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

> sidebar.component.css

```
.full-layout-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.no-margin {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I want to add a margin around `inner-content`, so that it has a margin of `5px` underneath of my `mat-toolbar`, and on all other sides.  When I currently apply the margin, the page scrolls, which I believe is due to the absolute positioning on my header.  I can get it to work when I know the browser height, but I am unsure of how to make it scale to all browser sizes.

What I would like to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
```

where 60px = 5px margin x2 + 50px example of header height, so then you content is accurate on whole screen with margins

Comment: 2 ways: use padding-top = header height on whole page, then content is not absolute position, 2nd is add margin-top to content

Comment: remove `height: 100%`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-fveqzs?file=app/sidenav-autosize-example.css